# Can't create Appfabric DataCache instance

Tags: appfabric

I'm using AppFabric Server Cache version 1.1 for my MVC project. I got a ridiculous error that I can not explain why. I downloaded example project from "Windows Server AppFabric Training Kit" (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7956) and compare with my project. Both projects use:
 
- Same configurations ( host, cacheport...)
 
- Same AppFabric dll (Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client and Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core File version 1.0.4639.0) 
 
- Same Target Framework (.Net Framework 4)

But their project work fine and mine does not. Whenever reaching this line code 
`var cache = dcf.GetCache("default");` 
An exception throw:
`Field not found: 'Microsoft.Fabric.Common.IOCompletionPortWorkQueue.WORKER_THREAD_IDLE_WAIT_TIME'`

I googled it and got some explanations relate to GAC(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7686a113-cf57-4262-835a-d8c7a094677d/cant-create-appfabric-datacachefactory-using-latest-libraries-missingfieldexception)
However If so, the project that I downloaded from Training Kit must be throw exception too, right?

Anyway, I uninstall those dlls from GAC and mark 2 above dlls copytolocal = true. But the error still remains
Could anyone suggest me any possible causes for this error?
Thanks alot.